# Improving performance with Distributed Counter, looking for library

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

We have a system with many threads, each incrementing the same counter. At the end, we need the total number of increments of all threads.  Due to the size of the final result and the cost of synchronization, we suspect some performance issue with our current solution, which uses syncronized access to a single variable.

To avoid synchronization, I would like to use a Distributed Counter (correct term?), where each thread increments its own counter copy.  The individual counters are summed up only once at getting the final result.

I could implement such a counter from scratch.  But I guess, I'm not the first one with such a requirment.  Suprisingly, a quick search did not turn up any library. Could you suggest some library or demo code?  I'm looking for a simple solutions, no heavy framework.

Comment: Asking for tools, libraries, tutorials, or off-site resources recommendation is off-topic in here

Comment: I think you can use AtomicInteger.It will work without synchronization.https://winterbe.com/posts/2015/05/22/java8-concurrency-tutorial-atomic-concurrent-map-examples/

Comment: @NPE you are probably right. I just pointed it because the internal implementation idea of `LongAdder`  was similiar to what OP wants so I thought it might be useful.

Comment: Isn't AtomicInteger providing the opposite: synchronized atomic read/write access to a shared variable? I'm looking for frequent non-synchonized write access to duplicated variables, to which a synchronized read access occurs only once

Comment: is it 1 JVM process with many threads, or does this need to work across different JVM processes?

Comment: The solution you propose yourself is a CRDT counter. Perhaps searching for that keyword let's you find a suitable implementation.

Comment: @jmg. Thanks! Could you add your comment as answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: @UlrichScholz what did you end up doing?

Comment: @UlrichScholz As you asked, I've added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you propose yourself is a CRDT counter. Perhaps searching for that keyword let's you find a suitable implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Does your system have many different processes managing all the different threads?

if all threads are managed by the same process i don't think you need a distributed resource (counter) you can just use as suggested an [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) 
Atomic means that it is thread safe and can be accessed from many threads and no data corruption will happen.

if your system does use many processes than you will need a distributed resource.
you can use any type of database in order to achieve that. 
seems to me that [Redis](https://redis.io/) might be a good option.
or any MySql Database if you want 100% Data consistency

Comment: @Ulrich Scholz reading the chat it seems like your are trying to solve a performance issue? is there one?  AtomicInteger might be a simple straightforward solution and it will be good enough, it all depends on how robust you system is or you want it to be.

Comment: @Ulrich Scholz just a thought, if you are in a single process  you could still have multiple thread counters as each tread finishes to count you can add the counter value to the shared atomic integer

Comment: @Ulrich Scholz what did you end up doing?

Comment: by now I did nothing. Although the counters show numbers in the low hundred millions, removing counting entirely did not improve performance. So, I did not invest any effort to replace them. To be honest, I'm surprised

Comment: OK got it, hope you find the problem

Answer (score 0):

If it is within 1 JVM process, just read thread local counters to sum them up.

If it is inter-process, **memory mapped files are great for performance** and *only* file level (or buffer level) I/O API fiddly when it comes to reading and writing.